# why doesn't the the Routes recognize te component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

i'm creating a Portfolio for myself and im using Angular 12 for it.
i have problems with Routing although i went through all the <angular.io> instruction.
i'm creating an stack Blitz for better demonstration [My Portfolio](https://stackblitz.com/edit/portfolio-for-p?file=src/app/app-routing.module.ts)

the aboutme component do not show after i click on the about me link in the app.component

Comment: What answer do you expect?

Comment: i had forgot to ask actually :)

Comment: your code throws an error, I dont see any links. please provide reproducable example, otherwise, I'd willing to bet - your question will be downvoted an closed

Comment: I saved the Changes. now there is no error and there is a link  and there is some text in the aboutme component.

Comment: Now it works. I don't know how to answer but I hope your question will survive ))

Comment: look. i have a link which by clicking should go to aboutme component. i doesn't work. that is it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make mistake in your routing module
I fixed that and you make mistake in your selector in AboutMe component

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AboutMeComponent } from './aboutme/aboutme.component';

const routes: Routes = [{ path: 'aboutme', component: AboutMeComponent }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```